# Flex-layout gutter in both side on mobile

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I'm using flex-layout with this code

```
<div class="auth" fxLayout>
  <div class="auth__hint" fxHide.xs="true" fxFlex="50%">Item 1</div>
  <div class="auth__form" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

and it works fine but now I want to set a gutter of 15px
on both side I've tried with

```
<div class="auth__form" fxFlexOffset.xs="15px" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

but it sets only margin-left.

How can I manage the gutter on both side 
with the flex-layout breakpoints (I mean without any other extra code)?

Comment: have you try `space-around`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it doesn't work.I've almost worked it out with  fxFlex.xs="95%" but its not the same I'd like more a fixed value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngStyle` like this:

```
<div class="auth" fxLayout>
  <div class="auth__hint" fxHide.xs="true" fxFlex="50%">Item 1</div>
  <div class="auth__form" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="100%" ngStyle.xs="margin: 0 15px;">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's the result:

[image]

I do not know if [fxFlexOffset](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlexOffset-API) supports `margin-right`:

> RTL support is coming soon, which will automatically apply
>   margin-right instead of margin-left